# Intellij idea + mac. Или откуда лаги?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, macos, mac, jetbrains

Совсем недавно я стал обладателем нового MacBook Pro 16 на i9 с 32гб оперативы.
Это мое первое знакомство с macOS и вроде все нравилось и кажись я был счастлив до того как я не перешел работать со своего станционарника на Убунте на этот Mac. Я Java разработчик и мак взял в надежде что смогу полноценно мобильно работать имея этот аппарат под рукой, и по началу все шло хорошо, контейнера поднимаются терминал почти тот же, развернул все окружение за полтора дня и приступил работать, как наткнулся на проблему там где ее совсем не ждал.

Мощей в нем безусловно за край для разработки, но почему же тогда Intellij idea подлагивает? Я вообще не привередливый пользователь в целом, но когда я совершаю самые простые действия и мой старый комп с ryzen 3 1200 отрабатывал моментально даже если задеплоенно 5 небольших сервисов, а новый мак хоть и не на долго но подтормаживает, я потихоньку да кидаюсь в бомбешь.

Рассмотрим конкретные примеры:

- Открываем проект и ждем когда он полностью проиндексируется. После
  открываем какой нибудь класс - не большой ну пусть будет строк 100,
  после открытия глядим в верхний правый угол редактора и там написано
  "Analyzing" - стандартная операция анализа содержимого класса которая
  отрабатывает когда открываешь класс в первый раз.

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

  Она может длится даже с маленькими классами две три секунды . В
  момент когда происходит этот анализ двигаем тачпадом в верх низ и
  видим что все подлагивает (в этот момент все подлагивает в Идее)
- Второй случай проще, периодически когда вызываешь метод или прописываешь название класса и в момент когда Идея хочет тебе подсказать, печать подвисает (буквы не моментально пропечатываются).
- Остальные кейсы сравнимы со вторым - подвисание происходит в момент когда идея задумывается.

Может кому то покажется что это мелочи, но  ̶ф̶а̶к̶ на убунте или той же винде таких подвисаний не было, а на всеми хваленном аппарате.... В гугле ничего толкового нет и все равно мне кажется что возможно я чего то не знаю, либо с этим действительно приходится мириться?
Да кстати в PyCharm подобных зависаний не наблюдаю. Если у кого есть какие мысли например как этот Analyzing сделать сразу для всех классов из проекта и чтоб потом над каждым по отдельности анализ не проводился то Welcome.

Comment: можно попробовать увеличить лимит памяти для виртуальной машины в ее конфиге https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544869-Configuring-JVM-options-and-platform-properties, например увеличить `-Xmx`

Comment: Наблюдаю подвисания, причем зачастую весьма хардкорные - на полминуты, во всех Intellij* продуктах jetbrains на всех платформах независимо от количества выделенной оперативной памяти. "Это норма" ©. Наверное это не должно удивлять, ведь они используют Java. Я бы даже сказал, что при всех подтормаживаниях, для продукта, написанного на Java, они работают на удивление шустро.

Comment: Понаберут своих маков, а потом мучаются)))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У меня тоже Macbook Pro 16 и я тоже Java программист и пользуюсь Intellij IDEA. Всё дело в macOS Big Sur. До её выхода, когда стояла Catalina всё просто летало и никаких лагов. После перехода на Big Sur появились подлагивания (они, кстати, проявляются не только в IDEA) и некоторые программы стали запускаться медленнее. Я долго ждал когда же Apple выпустит обновление, которое исправит эту ситуацию, но этого до сих пор так и не произошло.

Для того, чтобы вы наслаждались своим маком, а не думали о том как же так вы спустили столько бабла на лагучий кусок железа, вам нужно сделать откат на macOS Catalina. К сожалению, нельзя выполнить откат с сохранением данных на диске. Следовательно, если решитесь, то основной раздел диска придётся форматировать.

Я пользовался функцией восстановления через Internet. Для этого при перезагрузке мака зажмите на клавиатуре Shift + Option + Command + R. Укажите маку свою wi-fi сеть и он скачает утилиту восстановления через интернет и запустит её. В этой утилите вам сначала нужно форматнуть основной раздел вашего мака (у меня он называется Macintosh HD - Data), а после этого запустить установку Catalina (Если не форматировать диск, то установщик каталины не будет видеть ни одного диска подходящего к установке и вам всё равно придётся возвращаться к дисковой утилите). В результате установщик скачает Catalina и установит её.

Попользовавшись Каталиной вы поймёте, НАСКОЛЬКО лагал ваш мак на Big Sur. Ну и, естественно, на Big Sur не обновляйтесь, мониторьте англоязычные форумы Apple, там люди жалуются на сходные проблемы с Big Sur (лагают даже Mac Pro, которые стоят по миллиону рублей и выше).